# Hide notification of foreground service while activity is visible

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

Is their a way to start a service as a foreground service and hide the notification while an activity is visible?

Consider a music player, while the app is opened, you don't need the notification (with i.e. the buttons), but whenever the music player is in the background, the notification should be shown.

I know, how to do this, if I DON'T run my service in foreground... But when running in foreground, the service itself needs the notification and shows it and I can't manage the notification by myself...

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this. One prerequisite to this method is, that your activity must *bind* the service.

First you start service foreground.

```
private Notification mNotification;

public void onCreate() {
   ...
   startForeground(1, mNotification);
}
```

Then in your activity you bind and unbind the service as shown below. `BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY` is important for keeping service alive for the time it is bound to visible activity.

```
public void onStart() {
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY);
}

public void onStop() {
    ...
    unbindService(mConnection);
}
```

Now here is the last past. You stop foreground, when at least one client is connected to the service, and you start foreground, when last client disconnects.

```
@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    stopForeground(true); // <- remove notification
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    stopForeground(true); // <- remove notification
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    startForeground(1, mNotification); // <- show notification again
    return true; // <- important to trigger future onRebind()
}
```

When binding a service, you have to consider rules applied by Android. If you bind a not started service, the service will not start automatically unless you specify `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag in addition to `BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY` flag.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE 
            | BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY);
```

If service was started with auto creation flag on, and last client unbinds then service will stop automatically. If you want to keep service running you have to start it with `startService()` method. Basically, your code will look like the one below.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY);
```

Calling `startService()` for already started service has no effect on it, as we do not override `onCommand()` method.

Comment: seems to do what I want... only one disadvantage, I have to start the service before I actually need it...

Comment: Just finished the implementation. It should work well. The answer was updated.

Comment: I tried it before, didn't work perfectly... I will check the changes and have a look on it again... By the way, not binding the service and sending an intent in the activities onPause/onResume to change the foreground state of the service would not work, because the service may be killed while the activity is active? Can this really happen? Or would that work as well?

Comment: I needed it in my project too, so I made it working. onUnbind() returns true, onRebind() hides notification. Regarding your question. Binding service is a must. If it's not bound, it can be killed with much higher probability. And this really happens on devices with smaller amount or RAM.

Comment: still one question... startService says, that it will overrides the default service lifetime that is managed by onBind... but you say, that onBind THOUGH is necessary, to keep the service alive?

Comment: startService() is only needed if you want to let service run after you unbind from it. If you are ok that service stops after unbind, then you can omit startService() call. Try both options out, and you will see the difference.

Comment: I want to keep it run... that's why I'm asking... I know everything works my way as well, I am just not sure if the binding has really an advantage... Because of what I wrote about startService... if binding only serves the purpose of updating the foreground status, it has no advantage over sending update intents for the same purpose... Btw, this question only occurs because startService says, that if OVERRIDES the default service lifetime that is managed by onBind...

Comment: I see. BIND_ADJUST_WITH_ACTIVITY flag ensures that background service (a service without notification icon) has higher priority and won't be killed until activity is visible. If you don't bind, then you'll have no such insurance and your service can be killed. "startService() overrides" means your service won't be stopped after unbind. If this is an expected behavior - just ignore this "override" warning.

Comment: ok, thanks for that info... didn't know that binding will set a higher priority to the service... Just to complete that, setting the priority via IntentFilter would have the same result, wouldn't it? I must commit though, I did not try that...

Comment: IntentFilter priority has nothing to do with process priority.

Comment: I'm doing this exact same thing, but when I call `unbindService()`, I get a ServiceLeakException.  Any idea why this is happening?  I've grepped through with the debugger and I've made sure that `bindService(...)` is called only once as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use following steps:

1.Use ActivityManager to get current package name(i.e the Activity Running on top).

2.check if its your application then do not show the notifications

3.else If it is not your application then show the notifications.

```
ActivityManager manager =(ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
                            String topActivityName = tasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                            if(!(topActivityName.equalsIgnoreCase("your package name"))){
 //enter notification code here
}
```